# google.maps is undefined in Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, google-maps

I have the next code:

```
{% extends "block.html" %}

{% load media_tags staticfiles %}

{% block blocktitle %}{% endblock %}

{% block blockbody %}

{% addmedia "css" %}
  <link href="{% static "merengue/css/map/map.css" %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
{% endaddmedia %}

<script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style type="text/css"> html, body, #map { height: 100%; margin: 0; }</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var blocked_maps;
    var setup_blocked_maps;
    var map;

    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;key=AIzaSyBwdVf-Ezph3llEXy-cK0HnTLLfGEx3p-Q&libraries=places';
    //script.defer = true;

    if (! blocked_maps) {
        blocked_maps={}
    }
    blocked_maps["#mapblock_{{ reg_block.id }}"]={
                    use_cluster: false,
                    show_directions: false,
                    {% if render_ui %}
                    use_small_controls: true
                    {% else %}
                    no_ui: true
                    {% endif %}
                };

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
        map: map
  });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

<div id="mapblock_{{ reg_block.id }}" style="width: {{ width }}px; height: {{ height }}px;">
  <div class="mapParameters hide">
    <span class="zoom">{{ zoom }}</span>
    <span class="longitude">{{ longitude|safe }}</span>
    <span class="latitude">{{ latitude|safe }}</span>
    <span class="markersShownInitially">1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="mapPoint hide">
    <span class="longitude">{{ longitude|safe }}</span>
    <span class="latitude">{{ latitude|safe }}</span>
    <span class="iconImage">{% static "merengue/img/map/default_map_icon.png" %}</span>
  </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

If I run this code, give the error:
You have included the Google Maps JavaScript API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.

So i comment the line:

And then I have the error: Cannot read property 'Map' of undefined in the line  var map = new google.maps.Map(...)

The problem is that google.maps is not defined and i dont know how fix this.

Comment: BTW its never a good idea too include your API key in public, please make sure to remove it!

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple `script` elements loading maps script and hence the error. Update your code to:

```
{% extends "block.html" %}

{% load media_tags staticfiles %}

{% block blocktitle %}{% endblock %}

{% block blockbody %}

{% addmedia "css" %}
  <link href="{% static "merengue/css/map/map.css" %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
{% endaddmedia %}

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;key=AIzaSyBwdVf-Ezph3llEXy-cK0HnTLLfGEx3p-Q&libraries=places" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style type="text/css"> html, body, #map { height: 100%; margin: 0; }</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var blocked_maps;
    var setup_blocked_maps;
    var map;

    if (! blocked_maps) {
        blocked_maps={}
    }
    blocked_maps["#mapblock_{{ reg_block.id }}"]={
                    use_cluster: false,
                    show_directions: false,
                    {% if render_ui %}
                    use_small_controls: true
                    {% else %}
                    no_ui: true
                    {% endif %}
                };

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
        map: map
  });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

<div id="mapblock_{{ reg_block.id }}" style="width: {{ width }}px; height: {{ height }}px;">
  <div class="mapParameters hide">
    <span class="zoom">{{ zoom }}</span>
    <span class="longitude">{{ longitude|safe }}</span>
    <span class="latitude">{{ latitude|safe }}</span>
    <span class="markersShownInitially">1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="mapPoint hide">
    <span class="longitude">{{ longitude|safe }}</span>
    <span class="latitude">{{ latitude|safe }}</span>
    <span class="iconImage">{% static "merengue/img/map/default_map_icon.png" %}</span>
  </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```